# Query.RankingModelID - empty

Tags: 2010, search, query, xml

In SharePoint KeywordQuery, if query attribute RankindModelID will have empty string assigned to it - will search engine use default ranking model for given search application instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation and testing: the answer is yes. If given none or empty ranking model id in query parameter, Sharepoint search engine will use ranking model set as default.